# Deployment pitfalls for VSTO and ClickOnce

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, ms-office, clickonce

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with an Excel Workbook 2007 VSTO project.

It is using .NET 4 and the VSTO4 runtime.

I am using ClickOnce to publish this.

The prerequisites I have set are .NET 4, VSTO runtime, and Windows installer.. I have not included the Primary Interop Assemblies.

I have set this to download from the same location as my application.

After publishing when I get a user who has only .NET installed on their machine.. and they try to open the Excel Workbook to see what happens, they get an error of `"The common language runtime could not be loaded... Contact an administrator"`

I also tried running the "setup.exe" for this user and even clicking directly on the VSTO4 runtime installer and I got the message of `"Do not have the required administrator privileges"`

Can anyone confirm to me that the only way I can use a ClickOnce project for Office is for the user to have Administrator access?

Comment: Thanks do you want to add that as an answer? so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Admin rights to install prerequisites like the VSTO run time. The actual Add-In does not require Admin rights.